# What is `|slice|`?

Tags: rust

Can anyone explain to me how the `|slice|` in this statement work?
Source (l35): https://gist.github.com/madhavanmalolan/b30b47640449f92ea00e4075d63460a6

```
let amount = rest_of_data
      .get(..8)
      .and_then(|slice| slice.try_into().ok())
      .map(u64::from_le_bytes)
      .unwrap();
```

Comment: It's a closure that receives one argument named `slice`. Anything in particular you don't understand about it?

Answer (score 1):

This code tries to transform a byte array to a `u64`.

```
let amount = rest_of_data  // &[u8]
  .get(..8)                // Option<&[u8]>
  .and_then(|slice /* &[u8] */ | slice.try_into().ok()) // Option<[u8; _]>
  .map(u64::from_le_bytes) // Option<u64>
  .unwrap();
```

`rest_of_data` is a reference to a `[u8]`. `get(..8)` method tries to get the first eight elements of the `rest_of_data`, returns an `Option<&[u8]>` (`Some` if there are at least eight elements present in the slice and `None` if there are fewer.)

As for your question;

To transform some bytes to `u64` using `u64::from_le_bytes`, your input needs to be an owned value, not a reference. By calling `.and_then(f)` on `Option<&[u8]>` you give the closure `f` the `val` in `Some(val)` in this case it's `&[u8]`. Closure `f` takes one argument (named `slice` in this example) and returns the closure result. Then this returned value is fed to `u64::from_le_bytes` with `.map()` method.

Since `u64::from_le_bytes` takes an owned value, you need to transform the byte slice into an owned type, which is what the closure does with the `.try_into()` function. It gives you a byte array.